# Spring Boot JSR303 message code in annotation getting ignored

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

In my Spring Boot app I have a backing bean where I am using JSR303 validation.  In the annotation, I have specified the message code:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{firstname.isnull}")
private String firstname;
```

Then in my message.properties I have specified:

```
firstname.isnull = Firstname cannot be empty or blank
```

My JavaConfig for the messageSource is:

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

The validation works correctly but instead of seeing the actual string, I get the message code in my jsp page.  In looking at the log file, I see an array of codes:

```
Field error in object 'newAccount' on field 'firstname': rejected value []; codes [NotBlank.newAccount.firstname,NotBlank.firstname,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [newAccount.firstname,firstname]; arguments []; default message [firstname]]; default message [{firstname.isnull}]
```

If I change the my message code in the message.properties to one of the codes in the array, the string displays correctly in my web form.  I didn't even have to change the code in the annotation.  This indicates to me the code in the message parameter of the annotation is getting ignored.

I don't want to use the default code.  I want to use my own.  How can I make this work.  Can you please provide a code example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSR303 interpolation normally works with `ValidationMessages.properties` file. However you can configure Spring to change that if you want (I was lazy to do so :)) e.g.

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

Comment: Awesome!  I just had to change the filename to ValidationMessages.properties and it worked!  I didn't even need the @Bean configuration (as I am using SpringBoot). I would up vote your answer but apparently I need a better reputation.  Thanks!

Comment: glad to help. if the solution works, you can at least accept it (I believe)

Comment: Accepted.   Looks like some kind soul up voted.  thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

According to [JSR-303 specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#default-resolution-algorithm) message parameters are expected to be stored in `ValidationMessages.properties` files. But you can override the place where they are looked for.

So you have 2 options:

1. Move your messages to the `ValidationMessages.properties` file
2. Or override `getValidator()` method of your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`'s descendant (`JavaConfig` in your case):

   ```
   @Override
   public Validator getValidator() {
       LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
       validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
       return validator;
   }
   ```

Comment: The verbiage in the specification states "**often** materialized as the property file /ValidationMessages.properties and its locale variations" (emphasis mine). The filename is not prescribed in the specification.