# In Bean Validation 1.1, change default resource bundle

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation

In Bean Validation 1.1, how do I change from the default ValidationMessages.properties, and use my own resource bundle?

I've seen this related issue, but it doesn't provide a solution:  [How to change location of ValidationMessages.properties in Bean Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293157/how-to-change-location-of-validationmessages-properties-in-bean-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. This is not defined in the BV specs, but rather implementation-specific.  I'm using the reference implementation Hibernate validator. The simplest way to achieve this is using a PlatformResourceBundle:

```
Validator validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator(
                new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
                        new PlatformResourceBundleLocator( "MyMessages" )
                )
        )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```

See [using-specific-resource-bundle-locator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html#example-using-specific-resource-bundle-locator)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a file

```
yourProject\src\main\resources\ValidationMessages.properties
```

With your error messages like:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=My message, value: {value}
```

Comment: As far I understand, author has asked how to change path/name of `ValidationMessages.properties`.